# Takes two clicks for react bootstrap popover to show up

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, popover

I've run into an issue while trying to build a page that allows the user to click on a word and get its definition in a bootstrap popover. That is achieved by sending an API request and updating the state with the received data.

The problem is that the popover only appears after the second click on the word. The `console.log()` in `useEffect()` shows that every time a new word is clicked an API request is made. For the popover to appear the same word must be clicked twice. It'd be better if it only took one click.

```
    import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { Alert, Popover, OverlayTrigger } from "react-bootstrap";
    
    export default function App() {
      const [text, setText] = useState(
        "He looked at her and saw her eyes luminous with pity."
      );
      const [selectedWord, setSelectedWord] = useState("luminous");
      const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([
        {
          word: "",
          phonetics: [{ text: "" }],
          meanings: [{ definitions: [{ definition: "", example: "" }] }]
        }
      ]);
    
      const words = text.split(/ /g);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        var url = "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/" + selectedWord;
        axios
          .get(url)
          .then(response => {
            setApiData(response.data)
            console.log("api call")
           })
          .catch(function (error) {
            if (error) {
              console.log("Error", error.message);
            }
          });
      }, [selectedWord]);
    
      function clickCallback(w) {
        var word = w.split(/[.!?,]/g)[0];
        setSelectedWord(word);
      }
    
      const popover = (
        <Popover id="popover-basic">
          <Popover.Body>
            <h1>{apiData[0].word}</h1>
            <h6>{apiData[0].meanings[0].definitions[0].definition}</h6>
          </Popover.Body>
        </Popover>
      );
    
      return (
        <Alert>
          {words.map((w) => (
            <OverlayTrigger
              key={uuid()}
              trigger="click"
              placement="bottom"
              overlay={popover}
            >
              <span onClick={() => clickCallback(w)}> {w}</span>
            </OverlayTrigger>
          ))}
        </Alert>
      );
    }
```

**UPDATE**:
Changed the `apiData` initialization and the `<Popover.Body>` component. That hasn't fixed the problem.

```
    const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null)
    <Popover.Body>
            {
              apiData ?
                <div>
                  <h1>{apiData[0].word}</h1>
                  <h6>{apiData[0].meanings[0].definitions[0].definition}</h6>
                </div> :
                <div>Loading...</div>
            }
          </Popover.Body>
```

Comment: my guess is that the underlying issue of this is React's state. You're using a nested object for `apiData` so the lifecycle of this component from first look behaves in a way that it calls the api and sets new data to `apiData` but since that object is nested it doesn't get picked up right away and component doesn't get re-rendered, hence you need a second click which then updates `selectedWord` which in turn re-renders your app.

Comment: You are not calling `response.json()` in your `then` block. You should call it first before setting `apiData` state.

Comment: @moodseller Is there a way to circumvent that.  I'm also not sure that initalizing the state with a nested object is the right way.  But If I pass an empty array to apiData's `useState` an error is thrown in `<Popover.Body>`  because it can't access the fields of  the state.
@IshanBassi I've tried doing that but it didn't work. I think it's because `axios` converts the response to json by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Problem

Here's what I think is happening:

1. Component renders
2. Start fetching definition for "luminous".
3. The definition of "luminous" has finished being fetched. It calls `setApiData(data)`.
4. Component rerenders
5. If you click "luminous", the popper is shown immediately, this is because the data for the popper is ready to use and setSelectedWord("luminous") does nothing.
6. If you click another word, such as "pity", the popper attempts to show, but `setSelectedWord("pity")` causes the component to start rerendering.
7. Component rerenders
8. Start fetching definition for "pity".
9. The definition of "pity" has finished being fetched. It calls `setApiData(data)`.
10. Component rerenders
11. If you click "pity", the popper is shown immediately, this is because the data for the popper is ready to use and setSelectedWord("pity") does nothing.

Selecting another word will repeat this process over and over.

To fix this, you need to first make use of the `show` property to show the popover after rendering it out if it matches the selected word. But what if the word appears multiple times? If you did this for the word "her", it would show the popover in multiple places. So instead of comparing against each word, you'd have to assign each word a unique ID and compare against that.

#### Fixing the Component

To assign words an ID that won't change between renders, we need to assign them IDs at the top of your component and store them in an array. To make this "simpler", we can abstract that logic into a re-useable function outside of your component:

```
// Use this function snippet in demos only, use a more robust package
// https://gist.github.com/jed/982883 [DWTFYWTPL]
const uuid = function b(a){return a?(a^Math.random()*16>>a/4).toString(16):([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g,b)}

// Splits the text argument into words, removes excess formatting characters and assigns each word a UUID.
// Returns an array with the shape: { [index: number]: { word: string, original: string, uuid: string }, text: string }
function identifyWords(text) {
  // split input text into words with unique Ids
  const words = text
    .split(/ +/)
    .map(word => {
      const cleanedWord = word
        .replace(/^["]+/, "")     // remove leading punctuation
        .replace(/[.,!?"]+$/, "") // remove trailing punctuation
      
      return { word: cleanedWord, original: word, uuid: uuid() }
    });
  
  // attach the source text to the array of words
  // we can use this to prevent unnecessary rerenders
  words.text = text;
  
  // return the array-object
  return words;
}
```

Within the component, we need to setup the state variables to hold the words array. By passing a callback to `useState`, React will only execute it on the first render and skip calling it on rerenders.

```
// set up state array of words that have their own UUIDs
// note: we don't want to call _setWords directly
const [words, _setWords] = useState(() => identifyWords("He looked at her and saw her eyes luminous with pity."));
```

Now that we have `words` and `_setWords`, we can pull out the `text` value from it:

```
// extract text from words array for convenience
// probably not needed
const text = words.text;
```

Next, we can create our own `setText` callback. This could be simpler, but I wanted to make sure we support React's mutating update syntax (`setText(oldValue => newValue)`):

```
// mimic a setText callback that actually updates words as needed
const setText = (newTextOrCallback) => {
  if (typeof newTextOrCallback === "function") {
    // React mutating callback mode
    _setWords((words) => {
      const newText = newTextOrCallback(words.text);
      return newText === words.text
        ? words // unchanged
        : identifyWords(newText); // new value
    });
  } else {
    // New value mode
    return newTextOrCallback === words.text
      ? words // unchanged
      : identifyWords(newTextOrCallback); // new value
  }
}
```

Next, we need to set up the currently selected word. Once the definition is available, this word's popover will be shown.

```
const [selectedWordObj, setSelectedWordObj] = useState(() => words.find(({word}) => word === "luminous"));
```

If you don't want to show a word by default, use:

```
const [selectedWordObj, setSelectedWordObj] = useState(); // nothing selected by default
```

To fix the API call, we need to make use of the "use async effect" pattern (there are libraries out there to simplify this):

```
const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({ status: "loading" });

useEffect(() => {
  if (!selectedWordObj) return; // do nothing.

  // TODO: check cache here

  // clear out the previous definition
  setApiData({ status: "loading" });
  
  let unsubscribed = false;
  axios
    .get(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${selectedWordObj.word}`)
    .then(response => {
      if (unsubscribed) return; // do nothing. out of date response
      
      const body = response.data;
      
      // unwrap relevant bits
      setApiData({
        status: "completed",
        word: body.word,
        definition: body.meanings[0].definitions[0].definition
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (unsubscribed) return; // do nothing. out of date response
      
      console.error("Failed to get definition: ", error);
      
      setApiData({
        status: "error",
        word: selectedWordObj.word,
        error
      });
    });
    
  return () => unsubscribed = true;
}, [selectedWord]);
```

The above code block makes sure to prevent calling the `setApiData` methods when they aren't needed any more. It also uses a `status` property to track it's progress so you can render the result properly.

Now to define a popover that shows a loading message:

```
const loadingPopover = (
  <Popover id="popover-basic">
    <Popover.Body>
      <span>Loading...</span>
    </Popover.Body>
  </Popover>
);
```

We can mix that loading popover with `apiData` to get a popover to show the definition. If we're still loading the definition, use the loading one. If we've had an error, show the error. If it completed properly, render out the defintion. To make this easier, we can put this logic in a function outside of your component like so:

```
function getPopover(apiData, loadingPopover) {
  switch (apiData.status) {
    case "loading":
      return loadingPopover;
    case "error":
      return (
        <Popover id="popover-basic">
          <Popover.Body>
            <h1>{apiData.word}</h1>
            <h6>Couldn't find definition for {apiData.word}: {apiData.error.message}</h6>
          </Popover.Body>
        </Popover>
      );
    case "completed":
      return (
        <Popover id="popover-basic">
          <Popover.Body>
            <h1>{apiData.word}</h1>
            <h6>{apiData.definition}</h6>
          </Popover.Body>
        </Popover>
      );
  }
}
```

We call this funtion in the component using:

```
const selectedWordPopover = getPopover(apiData, loadingPopover);
```

Finally, we render out the words. Because we are rendering out an array, we need to use a `key` property that we'll set to each word's Id. We also need to select the word that was clicked - even if there were more than one of the same words, we only want just the clicked one. For that we'll check its Id too. If we click on a particular word, we need to sure that the one we clicked on is selected. We also need to render out the original word with its punctuation. This is all done in this block:

```
return (
  <Alert>
    {words.map((wordObj) => {
      const isSelectedWord = selectedWordObj && selectedWordObj.uuid = wordObj.uuid;
      return (
        <OverlayTrigger
          key={wordObj.uuid}
          show={isSelectedWord}
          trigger="click"
          placement="bottom"
          overlay={isSelectedWord ? selectedWordPopover : loadingPopover}
        >
          <span onClick={() => setSelectedWordObj(wordObj)}> {wordObj.original}</span>
        </OverlayTrigger>
      )})}
  </Alert>
);
```

#### Complete Code

Bringing all that together gives:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Alert, Popover, OverlayTrigger } from "react-bootstrap";

// Use this function snippet in demos only, use a more robust package
// https://gist.github.com/jed/982883 [DWTFYWTPL]
const uuid = function b(a){return a?(a^Math.random()*16>>a/4).toString(16):([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g,b)}

// Splits the text argument into words, removes excess formatting characters and assigns each word a UUID.
// Returns an array with the shape: { [index: number]: { word: string, original: string, uuid: string }, text: string }
function identifyWords(text) {
  // split input text into words with unique Ids
  const words = text
    .split(/ +/)
    .map(word => {
      const cleanedWord = word
        .replace(/^["]+/, "")     // remove leading characters
        .replace(/[.,!?"]+$/, "") // remove trailing characters
      
      return { word: cleanedWord, original: word, uuid: uuid() }
    });
  
  // attach the source text to the array of words
  words.text = text;
  
  // return the array
  return words;
}

function getPopover(apiData, loadingPopover) {
  switch (apiData.status) {
    case "loading":
      return loadingPopover;
    case "error":
      return (
        <Popover id="popover-basic">
          <Popover.Body>
            <h1>{apiData.word}</h1>
            <h6>Couldn't find definition for {apiData.word}: {apiData.error.message}</h6>
          </Popover.Body>
        </Popover>
      );
    case "completed":
      return (
        <Popover id="popover-basic">
          <Popover.Body>
            <h1>{apiData.word}</h1>
            <h6>{apiData.definition}</h6>
          </Popover.Body>
        </Popover>
      );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  // set up state array of words that have their own UUIDs
  // note: don't call _setWords directly
  const [words, _setWords] = useState(() => identifyWords("He looked at her and saw her eyes luminous with pity."));
  
  // extract text from words array for convenience
  const text = words.text;
  
  // mimic a setText callback that actually updates words as needed
  const setText = (newTextOrCallback) => {
    if (typeof newTextOrCallback === "function") {
      // React mutating callback mode
      _setWords((words) => {
        const newText = newTextOrCallback(words.text);
        return newText === words.text
          ? words // unchanged
          : identifyWords(newText); // new value
      });
    } else {
      // New value mode
      return newTextOrCallback === words.text
        ? words // unchanged
        : identifyWords(newTextOrCallback); // new value
    }
  }

  const [selectedWordObj, setSelectedWordObj] = useState(() => words.find(({word}) => word === "luminous"));
  
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({ status: "loading" });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!selectedWordObj) return; // do nothing.

    // TODO: check cache here

    // clear out the previous definition
    setApiData({ status: "loading" });
    
    let unsubscribed = false;
    axios
      .get(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${selectedWordObj.word}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (unsubscribed) return; // do nothing. out of date response
        
        const body = response.data;
        
        // unwrap relevant bits
        setApiData({
          status: "completed",
          word: body.word,
          definition: body.meanings[0].definitions[0].definition
        });
       })
      .catch(error => {
        if (unsubscribed) return; // do nothing. out of date response
        
        console.error("Failed to get definition: ", error);
        
        setApiData({
          status: "error",
          word: selectedWordObj.word,
          error
        });
      });
      
    return () => unsubscribed = true;
  }, [selectedWord]);

  function clickCallback(w) {
    var word = w.split(/[.!?,]/g)[0];
    setSelectedWord(word);
  }
  
  const loadingPopover = (
    <Popover id="popover-basic">
      <Popover.Body>
        <span>Loading...</span>
      </Popover.Body>
    </Popover>
  );

  const selectedWordPopover = getPopover(apiData, loadingPopover);

  return (
    <Alert>
      {words.map((wordObj) => {
        const isSelectedWord = selectedWordObj && selectedWordObj.uuid = wordObj.uuid;
        return (
          <OverlayTrigger
            key={wordObj.uuid}
            show={isSelectedWord}
            trigger="click"
            placement="bottom"
            overlay={isSelectedWord ? selectedWordPopover : loadingPopover}
          >
            <span onClick={() => setSelectedWordObj(wordObj)}> {wordObj.original}</span>
          </OverlayTrigger>
        )})}
    </Alert>
  );
}
```

Note: You can improve this by caching the results from the API call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As I started appying the changes layed out in your post I had to delete the `uuid()` function I had imported from the 'uuidv4' library and its assignment to the `<OverlayTrigger>` components in the main body. To my amusement that alone fixed the delay and popovers started appearing upon the first click. Still there was an issue with a small lag and a new popover for a split second displayed the definition for the previous word.

Comment: So I tried running your code and it had the same issue.To fix that I added `setApiData({ status: "loading" })` to the `useEffect()` and now it's working as intended. Thanks again.

Comment: @cruise134 RE: The UUID: annoyingly that makes a lot of sense. On each render, you'd generate a new UUID for the element. React would see this, delete the old component entirely and create a new element in its place. In my code above, the UUID that's used as the key stays the same between renders which means React just updates what it needs to.

Comment: @cruise134 RE: The loading status: I knew I was missing something. Glad to see you got it sorted. I'll fix that up now.